# Cant set multiple cookies via nextjs custom headers in next config

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, http-headers

I'm setting the cookie via custom headers in the next.config.js file. Only the refresh token gets set. The second token is ignored.

````
            key: 'Set-Cookie',
            value: `RefreshTokenKey = "some_token"; AccessTokenKey = "some_token"; SameSite=Strict; HttpOnly`,
          }```
````

Answer (score -1):

According to this documetation (read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie))

> The Set-Cookie HTTP response header is used to send a cookie from the server to the user agent, so that the user agent can send it back to the server later. To send multiple cookies, multiple Set-Cookie headers should be sent in the same response.

You should send multiple headers, like this:

```
{
    headers: [
        {
            key: 'Set-Cookie',
            value: 'RefreshTokenKey = "some_token";',
        },
        {
            key: 'Set-Cookie',
            value: 'AccessTokenKey = "some_token";',
        },
    ]
}
```